# Remove Bullets From Main Menu In Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, css-selectors

I am not a web developer so please bear with me on that.

I have a website (WordPress) that I'm trying to make a small update to before getting professional assistance.  I have updated this page https://www.trustserve.net/legal-privacy/ which you will see has bullets and numbers.  Originally when I input this text the bullets and numbers were appearing black.  I updated the CSS code which I will include below that fixed that issue.  The problem however is that my main menu at the top of each page now has a bullet next to it as well.

Main Menu:

[image]

I have seen numerous posts regarding bullets and WordPress sites but I can't connect the dots (no pun intended!) between those posts and my issue specifically.

I assume I need to add some HTML for the Main Menu specifically to remove the bullets but I don't know how to do that and this is what I need help with.  Any assistance that will help me remove bullets in my main menu without impacting the bullets on the other page is greatly appreciated.

My CSS updates are as follows:

```
ol {color: white } 

ol li::before {
    color: white;  
}

ul { list-style: none;} /* Remove default bullets */

ul li::before {
    content: "\2023"; /* Unicode bullet symbol */
    color: white;  /* Bullet color */
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Address only the `li`s in the (main) menu by using its ID in the selector and reset the `content` of the pseudo element you created:

```
#menu-main-menu li::before {
    content: "";
}
```

...or `content: none` in that rule. The difference will be the horizontal spacing between the menu items - choose which one you prefer.

Comment: Thank you Johannes, this worked perfectly!

Comment: thanks for your help again.  Marked as accepted.  I also voted up but my profile doesn't allow it yet.

Answer (score 0):

try to get rid of this *using content: "\2023";* code if you have access to the wordpress css theme, or just override it with your own css file by letting the string empty, as follows

```html
ul li::before {
    content: "";
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

That should work, and never underestimate the help of the inspector of your web browser ;)

Comment: Thank you for the response, this worked but it also removed the bullets from the other page.  The previous response did remove the bullets from the header only.  Thanks!

Comment: Oh sorry ! I haven't read correctly. Glad Johannes's solution worked !